# Navigation Menu not Outputing expected Snippet Value

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a code snippet like this one,

```
<div class="container">
            <ul id="menu">
                <li>
                    <a>
                        <i class="icon_about"></i>
                        <span class="title">Home</span>
                        <span class="description">Any Description Here Manual/Auto</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
</div>
```

And Im getting the list of `menu` items from this `php code`

```
<?php wp_nav_menu('menu=header_menu&container=false'); ?>
```

But the resultant of that cod is somehow like this,

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li class="page_item page-item-14">
            <a href="My_Link"> About Me </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

So, what im missing here is the `id="container"` inside the `<ul>` tag and after the `anchor tag <a>` the `<span>` . I dont really know how to put those I have a reference

```
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu
```

But the thing is I still cant understand as to how to add what the things Im missing from the snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's right there in the documentation:

> $menu_id: The ID that is applied to the ul element which encloses the menu items.
>
> $link_before: Output text before the link text
>
> $link_after: Output text after the link text

Using these three parameters should do the trick:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu('menu=header_menu&container=false&menu_id=container&link_before=<span class="title">&link_after=</span>'); ?>
```